# Django - get() returned more than one <entity> -- it returned 5

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django 1.8dev, and extremely new to django. I have a model based on a mysql `view` created like `create view arter_to_referencer as select ...`

```python
class SpeciesToReferences(models.Model):
    species_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='species_id')
    reference_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='reference_id')
    reference = models.CharField(db_column='Reference', max_length=255, blank=True, primary_key=True)
    beset = models.CharField(db_column='Set_', max_length=1, blank=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'arter_to_referencer'
```

serializers.py

```python
class SpeciesToReferencesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = SpeciesToReferences()
       id_field = 'species_id'
       fields = ['species_id', 'reference_id', 'reference', 'beset', ...]
```

views.py

```python
class SpeciesToReferencesList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SpeciesToReferences.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SpeciesToReferencesSerializer
```

All I want is to call `SpeciesToReferences` directly on our API :

```js
$http.get('/api/speciestoreferences/'+$routeParams.artsnummer).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

where `$routeParams.artsnummer` is 486 or any other value, or simply like this

```
http://localhost:8000/api/speciestoreferences/486/
```

It actually seems to work, if I inject 486 it returns the correct number of results, 5, and so on. But it keeps throwing the error :

> get() returned more than one SpeciesToReferences -- it returned 5!

How can I avoid that? The problem is that `species_id` not is unique, I guess, but I simply just want all occurrences where `species_id=X`.

Have read in the django manual, googling, read some "similar" stackoverflow questions - but no solution or explanation really helped me out. I think it should be possible to define class -> model -> view so it accepts multiple results for the dataset. I have the feeling that I should set some kind of filter on `SpeciesToReferencesList` but cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: Don't use a dev version, especially if you are new to Django. Use the released version, 1.7.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, yes - always a very good advice! I think I will do that tomorrow. But have not experienced difficulties with my collegue, who has installed 1.7 and we share code through github.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using [django rest framework](http://django-rest-framework.org) as well as Django. Instead of using a ViewSet, you may need to use a Generic View like [ListAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#listapiview). It can be used to provide [customer filters](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering).

```
Class SpeciesToReferencesList(ListAPIView):
  queryset = SpeciesToReferences.objects.all()
  serializer_class = SpeciesToReferencesSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    species_id = self.kwargs['species_id']
    return self.model.objects.filter(species_id=species_id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! Unfortunetely I know get an `as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)` but defently think you are heading me in the right direction. Need to understand this, and clearly there is something really basically I have missed :) You are compltely right, we are using the REST framework too ...

Comment: It's probably how you're registering the new view: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/933. When you register these views, you need provide the url conf. yourself. If you're still running into issues, I'd try the djangorestframework group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/django-rest-framework.